# Can I enumerate available WLANs?

Tags: windows-phone-7, wifi

I'd like to get information (for example SSID) of the WLANs which are available around me. Is this possible*?

**Edit:** *possible in the sense of "passes marketplace certification"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this isn't available in the current API set - and I don't think it's been mentioned in the Mango set either.

Comment: You can hope something of this sort will make it into Mango, with over 1500 APIs promised. But then again, MS might take the stance that an app has no business messing with available WLAN information, and I can see some logic to that argument. Configuring your WiFi setup is the OS' job, not a 3rd party app's ...

Comment: It's an interesting question - on WM6 the third party apps were much nicer to use for setting up the WiFi. I think for wp7, MS will be very cautious about exposing much in the way of "network" settings to apps - they seem much more cautious on security than Android. I am very much looking forward to seeing what comes in Mango though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was afraid to hear it is not possible (yet). I thought about using the SSID to provide some kind of location awareness for apps, I don't want to mess with network settings.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a pinvoke to WlanGetAvailableNetworkList.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.wlangetavailablenetworklist

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706749%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @spgennard: That will also guarantee that your app never passes marketplace certification

Comment: I think you can say stronger than that - if you try to use PInvoke, then it will fail certification. Would be very interested to hear about any Wp7 app that has passed while using PInvoke

Comment: The msdn link in this post is to a full Windows API, not a phone one.

Comment: Passing marketplace certification is a must, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Staurt: The "Stocks" app from HTC lists Interop Services in the app capabilities, but it is from HTC, not lowly developers like ourselves :)

Comment: @Preatorian - indeed - I've also seen somewhere a Samsung app that uses a compass via PInvoke... one day...