# Does the Windows Phone keep a log of cell towers or seen WiFis? Can I access it?

Tags: logging, windows-phone-7, wifi

With all the news out there about iPhones and Android devices storing logs of cell towers and/or WiFis an idea popped into my mind. What I *really* need is to enumerate available WLANs to provide some kind of location awareness - but this seems impossible right now (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679066/can-i-enumerate-available-wlans) on the topic).

Now if there was such a log on the Windows Phone *and* an API to access it I could just read this data from the log file. Should be ok for my purposes.

Does somebody know more about what the Windows Phone logs and if one can access these logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard Windows Phone SDK you cannot access any of the logs or system files but you do have access to the [Location service APIs](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/25/using-the-location-service-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone.aspx):

> The location service is a set of APIs that rely on Assisted-GPS (A-GPS), Wi-Fi Positioning System (WPS), and cell-site triangulation to expose location data to an application.

If you use non-public APIs you may be able to find un-documented features or log files, but your app would not be able to be published in the Marketplace and could only be released as a homebrew app.

Microsoft has stated that they do not keep a [history of your location on the phone](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/04/windows-phone-7-no-on-device-location-tracking-online-another-matter.ars). While you may be able to find a hack for what you are looking for it most likely would be device specific and you would severely limit which users could install your app (dev unlocked phones only). Your best bet is to try and find a way to use the Location Service to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the links! The essence seems to be: we don't save the stuff on the phone. Which answers my second question: no stuff, no access.