# Is it possible to programmatically get all surrounding wifi routers?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I am new to Windows Phone 7 Development.
I want to know, can I search Wi-Fi(WLAN) Access points around my phone, programmatically?

Comment: Please clarify: (1) search *for* other devices, that is to see if there are any devices around (e.g. WiFi routers), or (2) search their contents or other characteristics? If the second, I don't like the security implications of the question.

Comment: Could you expand on `wifi devices`? Please read the faq.

Comment: Actually i want to search WiFi routers only. Is it possible with windows phone 7 programmatically , because it is restricted in iphone development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I enumerate available WLANs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679066/can-i-enumerate-available-wlans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically accessing the list of access points and connecting is restricted in the Current version of WP7.0/7.1 because of the security reason.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Santhosh.

Comment: If you feel my answer is useful for you then please mark it as answer. Thanks,Santhosh